# How to unintall .net core 2.1 runtime in Windows 10

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I've mistakely install .net core 2.1 by VS 2022. Now I'd like uninstall it.
But, it seems like there isn't a good way to do this.

MSDN mentioned [.NET uninstall tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=windows)

But on Windows, the tool can only uninstall SDKs and runtimes that were installed using one of the following installers:

The .NET SDK and runtime installer.
The Visual Studio installer in versions earlier than Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3.

It also mentioned "uses the Windows Apps & features dialog to remove versions of the .NET runtime and SDK." But I can't find .net core 2.1 at there.

Is there anything else good way to uninstall it?

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it (click the check mark to the left of the answer) so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

First open **Visual Studio Installer** and simply Update Your Version if you want Update it. it automatically remove old version. and if you want to remove it than simply choice

> more > Uninstall

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for **Visual Studio Installer** in the taskbar and open it

[image]

2. Click Modify on the right side of the Visual Studio you are using

[image]

3. Find .NET Core 2.1 Runtime in Individual components, uncheck it and click Modify in the lower right corner

[image]

Then you will find that the .NET Core 2.1 Runtime has been removed after entering `dotnet --info` in cmd

[image]

**In addition**, it is not recommended that you "uses the Windows Apps & features dialog to remove versions of the .NET runtime and SDK." Because in my attempts, I found that it can install and uninstall .NET Framework 3.5 (include .NET 2.0 and 3.0 ), not .NET Core 2.1

[image]